# PHP - compatibility of <?= shortcut

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use)
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Hi Guys,

I can't seem to find any information about the `<?=` shortcut of php.
Does anyone of you know more about that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might like to see this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the PHP ini directive short_open_tag
It enables the support for `<?` instead of `<?php`

From the docs:

> ```
> Note:
>
> This directive also affects the shorthand <?=, which is identical to
> ```
>
> short_open_tag to be on.

There has been no announcement whatsoever that support should be discontinued. You can regard `<?=` as supported as `<?=`.

There are however some weird preconfigured systems that don't have it enabled by default.

For example some debian version in early php5 versions.

So to be on the save side you should do `<?php`

php.net also says:

> Note:
>
> Using short tags should be avoided
>   when developing applications or
>   libraries that are meant for
>   redistribution, or deployment on PHP
>   servers which are not under your
>   control, because short tags may not be
>   supported on the target server. For
>   portable, redistributable code, be
>   sure not to use short tags.

which i would interpret at, you are totally fine as long as you can control your settings.

Documentation is here: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php
and here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Answer (score 1):

The [document](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) when talking about `short_open_tag` directive says:

This directive also affects the shorthand `<?=`, which is identical to `<? echo`. Use of this shortcut requires `short_open_tag` to be `on`.

Answer (score 0):

The [manual entry](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php) on these short tags has this to say about compatibility

> Using short tags should be avoided when
>   developing applications or libraries
>   that are meant for redistribution, or
>   deployment on PHP servers which are
>   not under your control, because short
>   tags may not be supported on the
>   target server. For portable,
>   redistributable code, be sure not to
>   use short tags.